# For Loop Time Complexity Analysis

Tags: java, time, time-complexity

How to encounter Time complexity of such kind of loops?

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int n = 39;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; i<i*i; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 3; k<j; k = k*2)
            {
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am thinking time complexity will be `O(n^3 log n^2)` but I am really unsure about it.

Comment: Why are you thinking it would be `O(n^3 log n^2)`?

Answer (score 1):

Time complexity analysis is usually performed in `O` (*big O*).

If you have a simple loop that iterates over a collection of *n* entries, the time complexity will be `O(n)`.
If that loop skips saome items, the time complexity in terms of `O` will be the same. For certain purposes (not this one), you can also introduce the concept of *average*, *max* and *min*.

Your code,

```java
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int n = 39;
    for(int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 1; i<i*i; i++)
        {
            for(int k = 3; k<j; k = k*2)
            {
                    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

has 3 loops:

- loop 1: iterates on a collection of `n` elements, thus the loop is in `O(n)`.
- loop 2: here the for cycle is non canonical. The condition `i < i * i` is always true except for 0, therefore this program does not terminate in theory.

*From a theoretical point of view, this time complexity cannot be determined, since your code does not halt.*

What follows is a speculation for practical purposes.
If you consider that practically, we use arithemetic without overflow checks, *loop 2* will terminate sooner or later depending on the size of an integer (assuming 32 bit). The condition `i*i` is false for `i=46341`.

Loop 3 is never executed because of the condition is always false. So the time complexity of your code is constant on `p` where `p` is the first greatest machine number where the expression `p*p` overflows.